# Set and get kIsStationary bit using NSURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl

I'm porting some old `FSRef` code to use `NSURL`, `NSFileManager` and friends. Everything works except setting and getting the Finder `kIsStationery` bit on the file.

Is there a way to do this without falling back on deprecated `FSRef` methods?

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of research here is the answer for setting and getting the stationery bit:

```
struct FileInfoBuf
{
    u_int32_t info_length;
    union
    {
        u_int32_t padding[8];
        struct
        {
            u_int32_t type;
            u_int32_t creator;
            u_int16_t fdFlags;
            u_int16_t location;
            u_int32_t padding[4];
        }
        info;
    }
    data;
};

bool IsStationeryPad(const std::string& path)
{     
    attrlist attrList;
    FileInfoBuf fileInfo;

    attrList.bitmapcount = ATTR_BIT_MAP_COUNT;
    attrList.reserved = 0;
    attrList.commonattr = ATTR_CMN_FNDRINFO;
    attrList.volattr = 0;
    attrList.dirattr = 0;
    attrList.fileattr = 0;
    attrList.forkattr = 0;

    if (getattrlist(path.c_str(), &attrList, &fileInfo, sizeof(fileInfo), FSOPT_NOFOLLOW) == noErr)
    {
        return (CFSwapInt16BigToHost(fileInfo.data.info.fdFlags) & kIsStationery);
    }

    return false;
}

void SetStationeryPad(const std::string& path, bool isStationery)
{
    OSErr err = noErr;

    attrlist attrList;
    FileInfoBuf fileInfo;

    attrList.bitmapcount = ATTR_BIT_MAP_COUNT;
    attrList.reserved = 0;
    attrList.commonattr = ATTR_CMN_FNDRINFO;
    attrList.volattr = 0;
    attrList.dirattr = 0;
    attrList.fileattr = 0;
    attrList.forkattr = 0;

    err = getattrlist(path.c_str(), &attrList, &fileInfo, sizeof(fileInfo), FSOPT_NOFOLLOW);

    if (err == noErr)
    {
        fileInfo.data.info.fdFlags |= CFSwapInt16HostToBig(kIsStationery);

        setattrlist(path.c_str(), &attrList, &fileInfo.data, sizeof(fileInfo.data), FSOPT_NOFOLLOW);
    }
}
```

Note that there is no real error checking in this code. Also, applications probably shouldn't be setting this bit, this is really a user decision and shuld be controlled through the Finder.